# JQuery - focus triggers keyup event in target input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will demonstrate my problem using the simple example. Consider the following script

```
   $(document).on('keydown','#input1', function(e) 
   {        
      if(e.keyCode==13){ $("#input2").focus(); }    
   });
```

and HTML

```
   <input type="text" id="input1"/>
   <input type="text" id="input2" onkeyup='alert("UP")'/>
```

every time I press enter in the first input, focus goes to the second input but keyup event is triggered also. I tried stopPropagation but it does not work. How can I prevent that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you could use `keyup` instead of keydown

```
$(document).on('keyup','#input1', function(e) 
{        
    if(e.keyCode==13){ $("#input2").focus(); }    
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HNVSw/)